# Odd shadows are jagged and spikey

Tags: shadows

Why are the shadows cast from a "point light" on the left hand side so jagged and spikey? The chest's lid demonstrates it best. I would expect a smoother line parallel with the castee.

I can't understand how the fairly straight & smooth lines of the object are causing this?

The light is a spot light, 3000w, diffuse/specular/volume are set to 1:00 (max).

I hope someone can suggest why this might be happening, and would appreciate any guidance in any areas of improvement or amelioration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello are you using Eevee? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, Moonboots. Cool name. Switching it to Cycles has done a great job of removing those parts, so thank you. You wouldn't use cycles while editing etc? and if this was an animated treasure chest, rendering it in cycles, is there anything i should know to keep the render time manageable?

Comment: Eevee is not as good as Cycles for lights and shadows but maybe try to tweak the shadow parameters of the light and also the shadow parameters in the Render panel

Comment: Thanks, MB. If i did share my file alright, do you think you could do a quick favour and hop in there to check out why when i zoom out things dissapear? This is something i keep getting on my projects. I would prefer to zoom out infinitely without things suddenly dissapearing.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about the Clip? In the N panel > View > View > Increase the Clip End? If you're talking about your camera view, select the camera and go into the Camera panel > Lens > Clip End...

Comment: thanks, great video on boolean. Subbed from me. Merci mille, c'est chouette

Comment: Thanks, not enough content in english unfortunately  ;)

Comment: In the Render panel > Shadows > increase the Cube Size value, it will improve the shadows

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a star

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eevee is not as good as Cycles for lighting and shadows, that said you can tweak the light shadows parameters and also in the *Render* panel >*Shadows*, increase the values (particularly *Cube Size* I guess):

[image]